# Is there a way to live stream audio from server without the local file?

Tags: python, server, audio-streaming

I'm looking for a way to continuously stream audio from a server, the main issue is that the server side code it will receive many url's to stream audio. There will also be instances where the url is swapped live and a new piece of audio is streamed instead. I have not yet found a solution that wouldn't involve me downloading each file to then stream, which would hinder the live feature.

I've attempted to use vlc for python but it wouldn't allow for the ability to change the url being streamed in the moment. I've also attempted to use pyaudio but I haven't been able to get the correct audio format let alone swap the source of the audio.

An example link, *fairwarning it'll autoplay*:  [audio](https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/43f54fe0db841ed31dc0be0293b2f7deda53b1a9?cid=46535091c4d04072b1bd0de4b1f55852)

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit?  I assume you want to not just play the stream locally on the server, but also encode it and send it somewhere?

Comment: So the ultimate goal would be to offload the work of swapping out urls to the server, where the server would get the current live url and stream it to a client. I have been unable to find a method to avoid possibly downloading the audio and then rencoding it to send to the client.

Comment: Well, you need to re-encode it for sure.  But, you don't have to download it.  You can stream it through.

Comment: How can this be done where I can provide a consistent stream and change stream sources?

Comment: Can you answer the question though of where you're sending this stream?  SHOUTcast/Icecast?  DASH?  Something else?

Comment: I would have an open connection on the server, where the server url has access to the connection. Overall I'm attempting to put the server link in a webpage where I can stop/start/pause the clients connection to the stream.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's hard to give you any kind of a detailed answer without knowing the details of where the stream is going.  "server link on a webpage" doesn't tell me anything that I can use to help you.  Link to *what*?  What technologies?  What protocols?  The only advice I can give you is to split your playback and encoding sides so that you're playing out arbitrary media, decoding it *in realtime* to PCM, and then re-encode those PCM samples to whatever the stream goes to.  Since you've already tried automating VLC, continue with that.  It's a good choice for playout.

Comment: What does PCM stand for? I would be looking to use a socket, I'm new to server side stuff so I don't know too much about the protocols. I would be looking to open a socket connection on the server that would output the most recently transcoded audio. What is the best possible way to break it apart using VLC?

Answer (score 3):

To make a continuous stream that is sent to clients, you'll need to break this project into two halves.

## Playout

You need something to decode the source streams from their compressed formats to a non-compressed standardized format that you can manipulate... raw PCM samples.  Use a child process and have it output to STDOUT so you can get that data in your Python script.  You can use VLC for this if you want, but FFmpeg is pretty easy:

```
ffmpeg -i "http://example.com/stream" -ar 48000 -ac 2 -f f32le -acodec pcm_f32le -
```

That will output raw PCM to STDOUT as 32-bit floats, in stereo, at 48 kHz.  Once in this standard format, you can arbitrarily join streams.  So, when you're done playing one stream, just kill the process, switch to the next, and start playing back samples from the new one.

## Encoding

You want to create a single PCM stream that then you can re-encode with some external encoder, basically in reverse from what you did on playout.  Again, something FFmpeg can do for you:

```
ffmpeg -f f32le -ar 48000 -ac 2 - -f opus -acodec libopus icecast://...
```

Now, you'll note the output example here, I suggested sending this off to Icecast.  Icecast is a decent streaming server you can use.  If you'd rather just output directly over HTTP, you can.  But if you're playing this stream out to more than one listener, I'd suggest letting Icecast or similar take care of it for you.

Comment: Also note, as an alternative to doing this in Python, there's Liquidsoap.  I am personally not a fan of Liquidsoap as I've found it to be unreliable and difficult to use.  But, if you want code for all this, here's some I wrote years back:  https://bitbucket.org/radioreddit/radio-reddit-liquidsoap/src/c639c23f6e484f682f738ddee82b3eb973633493?at=master